# Lista retorna sempre somente o primeira linha do banco sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Tenho uma lista, que mostra todos os dados do banco sqlite, caminho da imagem,latitude e longitude, porem na lista somente altera o caminho da imagem, latitude e longitude sempre fica as do primeiro registro.

```
public List<Foto> todasFotos(){

    List<Foto> listaFotos = new ArrayList<Foto>();

    SQLiteDatabase db =  getReadableDatabase();

    String sqlTodasFotos =  "SELECT * FROM imagens";

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sqlTodasFotos,null);

    if (c.moveToNext()) {
        do {
            Foto foto = new Foto();
            foto.setId(c.getInt(0));
            foto.setCaminho_foto(c.getString(1));
            foto.setLatitude(c.getDouble(2));
            foto.setLongitude(c.getDouble(3));

            listaFotos.add(foto);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    return listaFotos;
}
```

Comment: Confira se o problema não está quando gravou os registos.

Comment: Verifiquei e realmente esta salvando a mesma latitude e longitude pra todos os registros, o estranho que estava funcionando ontem...Mas muito obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Poderia adicionar como faz o Insert? Como disse o @ramaral, o problema pode estar quando salvou!

Comment: Tenta tirar o **Foto foto = new Foto();** de dentro do looping

Comment: Tenta usar este SQL:  `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM imagens` e depois verifica o número que retorna em `c.getInt(0)`, este é o número de registros em seu banco.

Comment: Juliano, conseguiu resolver seu problema com a resposta? Ou precisa de mais alguma informação?

Comment: Consegui sim, muito obrigado !

Answer (score 3):

Use `moveToFirst()`. Considerando [a documentação do **SQLiteDataBase**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) diz-se respoeito que:

> Um objeto Cursor, que é posicionado antes da primeira entrada.

O `moveToFirst()` faz duas coisas:

1. Permite testar se a consulta retornou um conjunto vazio;
2. Move o cursor para o primeiro resultado (quando o aparelho não está vazio).

Considerando o `moveToNext()`:

```
while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

O cursor começa antes da primeira linha do resultado, por isso, na primeira iteração este move-se para o primeiro resultado se ele existir. Se o cursor estiver vazio, ou a última linha já terá sido processada, em seguida, o *loop* sairá ordenadamente.

O resultado final seria desta forma:

```
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Foto foto = new Foto();
            foto.setId(c.getInt(0));
            foto.setCaminho_foto(c.getString(1));
            foto.setLatitude(c.getDouble(2));
            foto.setLongitude(c.getDouble(3));

            listaFotos.add(foto);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
}
```

#### Detalhes

- [Cursor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html)
- [SQLiteDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Não vi nada de errado na resposta do @seamusd, não entendi o porque do -1, deve-se usar o `moveToFirst()` no if mesmo.. +1

Comment: @MarcoGiovanni Isso acontece o tempo todo! Até levei [uma discussão](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5312/qual-crit%C3%A9rio-de-avalia%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-uma-pergunta) para o Meta para saber como lidar com esse tipo de situação. E na resposta o nosso colega disse: "Não se preocupe demais com isso, faz parte. Eu recebo um monte de negativo que não entendo o porquê."...

Comment: Das questões que eu postei 2 tiveram respostas. Das respostas que eu dou recebo negativas. kkkkkkkkkkkk

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo Eu acredito que negativar acaba sendo uma questão de opinião quando não se é profissional. As vezes a pessoa não vai com sua cara e mete o (-1) sem pensar duas vezes.

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo o importante é tentar ajudar, fazer nossa parte sem olhar quem; isso é o conceito de comunidade.

Comment: O conteúdo da sua resposta não tem nada de errado, a questão é que ela não responde à pergunta do AP. O código da pergunta, apesar de não ser o mais habitualmente usado para percorrer um cursor, funciona, veja os comentários.

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo Você tem razão, o importante é ajudar, o problema é que estas respostas nada ajudam o AP. A ajuda e a resolução foi dada no primeiro comentário, lá na pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Veja assim:

```
public List<Foto> todasFotos(){

    List<Foto> listaFotos = new ArrayList<Foto>();

    SQLiteDatabase db =  getReadableDatabase();

    String sqlTodasFotos =  "SELECT * FROM imagens";

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sqlTodasFotos,null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

     if (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
               do {
                   Foto foto = new Foto();
                   foto.setId(c.getInt(0));
                   foto.setCaminho_foto(c.getString(1));
                   foto.setLatitude(c.getDouble(2));
                   foto.setLongitude(c.getDouble(3));

                    listaFotos.add(foto);
                 }
                  while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }

    db.close();
    return listaFotos;
}
```

Comment: Por que o voto negativo?

Comment: Não negativei, mas não positivei, pois desconheço o `!cursor.isAfterLast()`, acho que foi a mesma pessoa que negativou a resposta do seamusd

Comment: Serve para testar se o cursor não esta vazio. Se apesar de ter emitido o comando moveToFirst o ponteiro ainda esta além do fim do dataset então é certeza de que o cursor esta vazio.

Comment: O conteúdo da sua resposta não tem nada de errado, a questão é que ela não responde à pergunta do AP. O código da pergunta, apesar de não ser o mais habitualmente usado para percorrer um cursor, funciona, veja os comentários.

Comment: Para responder a questão dele é necessário corrigir o código dele.

Comment: O código dele funciona. O problema estava ao gravar.

Comment: Desculpe-me a insistência. Ele disse no titulo da pergunta que o problema estava no fato de retornar sempre a primeira linha eu não li que o problema estava na gravação. Eu entendi que estava retornando apenas a primeira linha porque ele não estava posicionando corretamente no cursor.

Comment: Sim, mas não há nada de errado com o código dele. Dar uma resposta no sentido de modificar o código(que funciona) não resolve o problema.